# Options grape representer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, grape-api, rails-roar, representable

I am working on a rails API with Representers, using the following gems: [Grape](https://github.com/intridea/grape), [Roar](https://github.com/apotonick/roar) and [Grape-Roar](https://github.com/dblock/grape-roar)

Now, I try to add conditions to include (or not include) certain properties in my representer based on a condition I pass from my API endpoint as described [here](https://github.com/apotonick/representable/#conditions) (note the representable gem is used by the Roar gem)

I'm probably overlooking something, but I can't figure out how to pass options to my representer, so I can present properties based on a condition

For example, in one of my grape endpoints I call:

`present payment_object, with: PaymentRepresenter, include_orders: true`

to present a payment object with PaymentRepresenter. As you can see I want to include related order for the payment as well, so in my Payment representer I tried to do:

```
property :order, extend: OrderRepresenter, if: lambda { 
    |args| puts args[:include_orders] #just puts for testing
}
```

however args[:include_orders] just is nil

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had this problem myself, and the only solution I came up with was to ditch nice idiomatic `present..., with:...` and manually `extend` my collection / record with representer, like this (concerning your example):

```
payment_object.extend(PaymentRepresenter).to_hash(include_orders: true)
```

Comment: thank you @yaro this totally works! For others: be sure to include `, env: request.env` in the to_hash() if you require environment variables in your representer, like I did, e.g. for PATH_INFO